# ActiveAdmin -- How to create join table records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I have two categories `merchants` and `aliases` who have a join table called `aliases_merchants`

In ActiveAdmin, **how can I display a textbox whose content will get entered into the joining table?**

I'm able to display the textbox but upon post it doesn't create the record in the joining table in the db.

Ideally, I would love to be able to get the functionality like the following (but I feel ActiveAdmin wouldn't be able to do it)...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a sidebar and two member functions in the ActiveAdmin resource to accomplish this. Works just described above.